# Trying to get horizontal scroll using a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal image slider using a table. I wanted 5 images to show, no matter the page width (it sizes correctly), however, the scroll is not working.

I suspect that I am using the wrong css with the table.

I do not need to use the table if there is a better way of going about this.

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsadm9qz/

**html**

```
 <div class="galleryWrap">
    <table border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="1" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+1" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="2" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+2" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="3" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+3" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="4" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+4" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="5" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+5" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="6" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+6" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="7" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+7" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="8" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+8" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="9" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+9" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="10" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+10" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="11" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+11" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="horizontalGalleryImageHolder">
                        <img id="12" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=IMG+12" style="max-height: 390px;" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0px;
}
img {
    width: 100%
}
.galleryWrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: A table isn't really ideal for this. Can you use anything else?

Comment: Yes, I tried using `inline-block` but failed that approach too, the table was just the closest I got. But anyway it can be done would be great, as long as I can still have only 5 images showing at a time with no spaces between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these styles:

```
td {
  display: inline-block;
}

table {
  white-space: nowrap;   //prevent cells from wrapping
}
```

[**Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/7y81hjtx/)

You could also simplify by getting rid of all the table HTML code, and using these styles:

```
.galleryWrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.horizontalGalleryImageHolder {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/7y81hjtx/2/)

Comment: I could of swore I tried that already! However, that is the exact effect I was looking for thanks!

Comment: **Fiddle 2** is also super clean, now I have choices! Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

https://jsfiddle.net/vsadm9qz/2/

Standard procedure for sliders is to inline-block the image containers and wrap them in two divs. The first has `overflow-x: scroll` and the second is made wide enough to accommodate all of the images.

Like so:

```
<div class="scroll">
   <div class="galleryWrap">
       <div class="image"><img></div>
```

and

```
.image{
   display: inline-block;
    width: 8% // 100 / number of images
}

img {
    width: 100%
}

.galleryWrap {
   width: 1200%; // 100 * number of images
}

.scroll {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: So it looks like if we were able to combine mine and yours, I would get the effect I am looking for, your fiddle slides but the images are not sized to the page, where-as mine have the correct image size but does not scroll. I cannot understand why it's not working :/

Comment: It is sized to the page. Due to your number of images (12) not dividing evenly into 100 (100/12 = 8.3333333), I rounded down to 8%. You can get it closer with a different number of images or with a different approximation (8.25%).

Comment: I took your fiddle and changed some things, the width needs to be about **1.7%** I have no idea why, or what it is relative too. The only issue i have now is how far the scroll goes past the images, because the width is so long, if I make the wrapper width shorter it makes the images smaller. see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vsadm9qz/5/

Comment: I think you may have mixed CSS from my Fiddle with your Fiddle. My Fiddle's images are correctly sized. I have no idea why yours needs to be 1.7%. You'd need to modify the .galleryWrap width. Remember, the `8%` is based on the `1200% = 100% screen width * 12 images` and `100 % gallery width / 12 images = ~8%`

Comment: Look at Rick's fiddles. That was what I was trying to get too. Thanks for taking the time to try to answer the question for me.